# How to print the prime number from javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to print the prime number from Java script. But this is not working. Can someone help me to figure the issue here.

```
var n=1000;
var i=3;

for( var count = 2 ; var count <= var n ; )
{
  for( var c = 2 ; var c <= var i - 1 ; var c++ )
  {
    if( var i% var c == 0 )
      break;
  }
  if ( var c == var i )
  {
    document.write( count +'th place' );
    document.write( i );
    var count++;
  }
  var i++;
}
```

Comment: `var` is only for declaring a variable. You don't need it when you access or reassign the variable's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `var` keyword way to often.

I corrected your code, take a look at how I used the `var` declaration, only at first assignment of a variables value:

```
<script>
    var n = 1000;
    var i = 3;

    for (var count = 2; count <= n; count++)
    {
       for (var c = 2; c <= i - 1 ; c++)
       {
           if (i % c == 0)
               break;
       }

       if (c == i)
       {  
           document.write(count + 'th place');
           document.write(i);

           count++;
       }
       i++;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but very related.

[Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

In short, checking if each number is prime is much slower than generating primes directly.